# Pause/Resume java applet

Tags: java, applet

two balls from left and bottom colliding with each other as they meet at a certain coordinate. I have already did what I searched on the internet and it worked perfectly, but I need a start, pause and resume buttons. Look at what I finished :

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class train extends Applet implements Runnable,ActionListener {
    private volatile boolean runs = true;
    private Image i;
    private Graphics doubleG;
    Ball b, b2;
    Button x,y,z;
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    @Override
        public void init(){
        setSize(800, 600);
        x = new Button("Action!"); 
        y = new Button("Stop");
        z = new Button("Resume!");
        add(x);
        add(y);
        add(z);


        y.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                runs = false;
                repaint();
            }
        }); 


        z.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                try {

                    runs = true;
                    b.update(this);
                    repaint();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }

                    b2.update2(this);
                   repaint();
            }
        }); 

    }





    @Override
    public void start(){
        x.addActionListener(this);
        b = new Ball(100, 100);
        b2 = new Ball(500, 500);
        }
    @Override

    public void run(){

        while(runs){
            b.update(this);
            b2.update2(this);   

            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void stop(){


    }
    @Override
    public void destroy(){

    }
    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(i == null){
            i = createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
        doubleG = i.getGraphics();
        }
        doubleG.setColor(getBackground());  
        doubleG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        doubleG.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(doubleG);

        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);

        }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        b.paint(g);
        b2.paint(g);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        thread.start();

     }


}
```

for the main train.class and :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Ball {


    private int x;
    private int y;
    private double dx = 7.9;
    private double dy = 7;
    private int radius = 20;


    public Ball() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public Ball(int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        x = i;
        y = j;

    }
    public void update(train sp){
                x += dx;

               //   if(x + dx > sp.getSize().width - 300){
        //      dx=0;
        //  }
                }


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);


        g.fillOval(x-radius, y-radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

    }
    public void update2(train sp){
        y -= dy;
        if(y - dy < sp.getSize().height - 470){

            x += dx;
            y -= dy;



        //  if(y < sp.getSize().height - 470){
        //      y = sp.getSize().height -470;
        //      dy *= energyloss;
        //      dy = -dy;
        //  }else{

        //      dy +=  gravity * dt;
        //      y += dy*dt + .5 * gravity * dt * dt;
            }
        //}
}
    public void update(ActionListener actionListener) throws InterruptedException {

        x += dx;
                }

    public void update2(ActionListener actionListener) {

    train tr = new train();


    if(y - dy < tr.getSize().height - 470){
        x += dx;
        y -= dy;
        }else{
        y-=dy;

        }





    }
}
```

What I want to do is I want to make a resume button. I already finished the start and pause, but when I click the resume button, it just moves 1 coordinate at a time. I need it to just like Start , pause and play normally. Please help. T_T

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix is to not have "runs" control the loop, but just determine whether or not the update method is called. That way you don't break the loop and have to restart.